# Pandas - Sum total for each date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Having a complete brainfreeze with what should be a simple pandas routine - but I am not having luck finding the answer.

I have a dataframe with three columns of interest for this - example below.

All I would like to do is add a new column called 'Pct_Day' that takes the percentage of each ID-date amount and divides by the total amount across all IDs for that date.

So for the example below, the result for the first row (8/7/17, ID: 553, Amount: 3) would be 0.25000 (3/(3+4+5))

Thank you for your help - need to get back in the Pandas swing...

```
df_dict={'DateOf': ['2017-08-07','2017-08-07','2017-08-07','2017-08-04','2017-08-04','2017-08-04'
                , '2017-08-03','2017-08-03','2017-08-03'], 'ID': ['553','559','914','553','559','914','553','559','914'], 'Amount': [3, 4, 5, 9, 11, 10, 3, 9, 10]}

df=pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps:

**Step 1: Calculate the sum of `Amount` for each Date**

```
df['sum'] = df['Amount'].groupby(df['DateOf']).transform('sum')
```

**Step 2: Calculate the percentage using the sum**

```
df['pct_day'] = df['Amount'] / df['sum'] * 100
```

Output:

```
   Amount      DateOf   ID  sum    pct_day
0       3  2017-08-07  553   12  25.000000
1       4  2017-08-07  559   12  33.333333
2       5  2017-08-07  914   12  41.666667
3       9  2017-08-04  553   30  30.000000
4      11  2017-08-04  559   30  36.666667
5      10  2017-08-04  914   30  33.333333
6       3  2017-08-03  553   22  13.636364
7       9  2017-08-03  559   22  40.909091
8      10  2017-08-03  914   22  45.454545
```

Finally,

**Step 3: Drop the sum column**

```
df.drop('sum', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

You can also do it in one line like this:

```
df['pct_day'] = df['Amount'] / df['Amount'].groupby(df['DateOf']).transform('sum') * 100
```

Comment: what is the different between yours and mine ?

Comment: same thing i guess. just breaking it down into steps

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You just need `transform` and div

```
df['New']=df.Amount/df.groupby(['DateOf']).Amount.transform('sum')
df
Out[51]: 
   Amount      DateOf   ID       New
0       3  2017-08-07  553  0.250000
1       4  2017-08-07  559  0.333333
2       5  2017-08-07  914  0.416667
3       9  2017-08-04  553  0.300000
4      11  2017-08-04  559  0.366667
5      10  2017-08-04  914  0.333333
6       3  2017-08-03  553  0.136364
7       9  2017-08-03  559  0.409091
8      10  2017-08-03  914  0.454545
```

Comment: Thank you very much